# fixed effects regression felm

Tags: r, regression, fixed, effects

I read several questions about the fixed effects regression with `felm()` (package lfe).

I am wondering what the `"rnorm(nlevels(..."` does. 
My regression works when I write the following code:

```
spieler.eff=rnorm(nlevels(spieler))
sfeT1=felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf,spieler.eff|0|0, data=datregT)
```

But why do I need to call `spieler.eff=rnorm(nlevels(spieler))` ?

I wrote the code like this because I've seen many others to do so. 
Actually I would have written

```
sfeT1=felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf,spieler|0|0, data=datregT)
```

but this does not work.

So my question is, what the `spieler.eff=rnorm(nlevels(spieler))` does.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Answer: `rnorm(n)` returns n draws from standard normal. You seem to be generating `length(nlevels(spieler))` length vector of random draws. I have no idea why you are doing that? Can you attach your data into your question by including the output of `dput(spierler)`. Also the exact error messages would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Otto! 
The output of dput(spieler) looks like the following:

"945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", 
"945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", 
"945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945228", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", 
"945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", 
"945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", "945368", ...

Comment: It is just a vector of several ID´s. It is in a data frame where I got several observations for each person.

I want to use spieler as an individual fixed effect in my regression: felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf,spieler.eff|0|0, data=datregT)

Comment: I used the spieler.eff=rnorm(levels(spieler)), because the regression did not work with just spieler as the fixed effect variable. The error when I run felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf,spieler|0|0, data=datregT) is: "Fehler in spieler | 0 : Operationen sind nur für numerische, logische oder komplexe Typen möglich" -> in english: Error in spieler | 0: operations are only possible for numerical, logical and complex types

Comment: Sorry, can edit the question above and include output of `dput(datregT)` to as a part of your question?

Comment: datregT is a data frame with many information about the competitions (I examine table-tennis competitions)

I regress the number of sets played on a dummy variable (which ==1  if the information of the computed chance of winning was given to the player)

Comment: According to `felm`, the correct syntax for the formula is `y ~ x1 | x:f1 | f2 | f3`. You seem to have an extra comma after `TTRVerf`

Comment: oh thanks otto! just tried it, you are right.

Comment: then i can now run my regressions with "spieler" and do not have to use the "spieler.eff"

Comment: glad to have helped. could I kindly ask you to approve my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to felm, the correct syntax for the formula is y ~ x1 | x:f1 | f2 | f3. You seem to have an extra comma after TTRVerf